# VB6: "Column 'name' not found" when trying to populate textbox from datagrid having db data

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I do not know what might be wrong but my visual basic 6 code gives me "column 'name' not found". There is a datagrid which gets populated from the database. All it's good until I try to populate a certain textbox with the data in a certain column. I try to do this with: `textboxColumnName.Text=mygrid.Column("columnName").Text`

Also I find it weird that some columns are detected. Particulary the one having a string as the data from the db. And the textbox gets populated in case of a string. The column that causes the error has,indeed, in db  an integer, but .Column(0).Text shouldn't parse the db integer into string or something like that?

And also,how is that possible, to tell me that the column is not found, taking into account that I can literally see the data from the db, into the datagrid. All I want is to get the data in the columns, into the textboxes.

I'm sort of a newbie in visual basic now(kinda have to use this) and don't know what to look for.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Anne. Please note that VB6 is *not* the same as VBA. If you use the wrong tags, the people who might be able to help you will not see your question. I've corrected the tag for this question. Please also take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions in the [help]. You need to ask very specific questions and provide sufficient background information so that people can understand exactly what you're asking. Your question is unclear and covers to much ground...

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. There are no columns in the grid with "name" for the name. Find the correct column name and replace "name" with the correct name of the column.

Comment: Also, your code example presumes that your table has a column called "columnName" in it, which seems unlikely.

Comment: Just came across this eerily similar question asked today. It should help answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286869/how-to-find-if-datagrid-contains-a-column