# How to find if dataGrid contains a column

Tags: vb6

Given an existing DataGrid called grid.

When I try to access `grid.Columns("column_name")` I get an exception

> Column not found, column_name

I tried

```
If Not IsNull(grid.Columns("column_name")) Then '...
```

but I still get the exception.

I would like something which I could call like

```
grid.ContainsColumn("column_name")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns in a DataGrid only have a caption text to identify what the column is so you could use something like this to check if the column exists by looking for a column with a Caption that matches the column name you are looking for.

```
Private Function DataGrid_CheckColumnExists(dataGrid As dataGrid, columnName As String)
    Dim columnCount As Long, columnIndex As Long
    Dim checkColumnName As String

    columnCount = dataGrid.Columns.Count

    For columnIndex = 0 To columnCount - 1
        checkColumnName = dataGrid.Columns(columnIndex).Caption

        DataGrid_CheckColumnExists = (StrComp(checkColumnName, columnName, vbTextCompare) = 0)
        If DataGrid_CheckColumnExists Then Exit Function 'No need to continue once we found it
    Next columnIndex
End Function
```